# I followed a tutorial to embed a csrf token and I am unsure if it secures the token properly

Tags: python, jinja2, csrf, flask-wtforms, csrf-token

I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.carsonevans.ca/2019/08/20/validating-ajax-requests-with-wtforms-in-flask/) to setup form validation with AJAX. It reads the csrf_token from an embedded element on the DOM which I am not sure is secure. I embed the token in 1 form and use that to read into all my other ajax requests. It works great, but I am not sure if this is the most secure way to handle this situation.

for reference here is my javascript for submitting a post.

```
async function submit_post() {
    const fields = {
        csrf_token: {
            input: document.getElementById('csrf_token'),
            error: document.getElementById('csrf_token-error')
        },
        body: {
            input: document.getElementById('body'),
            error: document.getElementById('body-error')
        }
    };
    const response = await fetch('/_submit_post', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            csrf_token: fields.csrf_token.input.value,
            body: fields.body.input.value
        })
    });
    data=await response.json();
    if (response.ok) {
        $('#siteModal').modal('hide');
        jFlash(data['text']);
        loadFactis(data['new_facti_id']);
        fields.body.input.value="";
    } else {
        const errors = data;
        Object.keys(errors).forEach((key) => {
           fields[key].input.classList.add('is-invalid');
           fields[key].error.innerHTML = errors[key][0];
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the jinja template I use to inject the CSRF token onto my page. I hide it in some code to open a modal:

```
<div class="post p-1">
    <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#siteModal" onclick="build_post_modal()" class="post_comment">
        <img src="{{ current_user.avatar(50) }}" class="profile_image">
        <input class="comment-input" id="post_body" placeholder="Make a post..." type="text" value="">
    </a>
</div>
<div id="post_modal" style="display: none;">
    <form id="post_template" autocomplete="off">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <!--<div class="text-danger my-2" id="csrf_token-error"></div>-->
        <div>
            <div class="profile-name">
                <img class="profile_image" src="{{ current_user.avatar(30) }}"/>
                <span>{{ current_user.username }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-icon mt-2 mb-2">
                <i class="bi bi-card-image hover" id="upload-icon"></i>
                {{ form.body(class='comment-input form-control', placeholder='Make a post...', autofocus=True) }}
            </div>
            <div id="body-error" class="invalid-feedback p-1"></div>
            <!--TODO tweek this for only images and add csrf-->
            <input id="filepond" type="file" class="hidden" name="filepond" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif"/>
            {{ form.submit(class='btn btn-secondary', style='width: 100%') }}
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually direct form submission (e.g. using button) without ajax does exactly the same: reads token from input, which is part of form, and POSTs to server. Token is not unique for each form (and there's no extra security in such feature).

Comment: It just seems like it would be easy for an attacked to copy the token from the dom and then use it to generate their own form which would defeat the purpose of the csrf token.

Comment: Yeah, and it remains true whenever you add this token. Set cookie? Okay, attacker can read it as well (and it's considered an even worse idea). Set JS global variable? Same here. Maybe there is more specific protection mechanism but I'm not aware of any. Actually there is a most widely used pattern: CSRF token is embedded into page as hidden input. Another (less common) common scenario is using custom HTTP header which are generally not allowed with cross-domain requests, but they're more difficult to use with XHR.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess it works better than I thought. Perhaps I'll try to fake my own token later.